# Inserting an id in a loop statement Oracle9

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, unique-constraint

I'm trying to insert a bunch of data in a table using a for loop. For the primary key I'm trying to use a sequence but I'm getting a:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated error.

My code look like this:

```
FOR a IN (select * from table a)
LOOP 

    select seq.nextval into id1 from dual;

    insert into table b (primarykey, value1...)

    select (id1, value1...) from table c

end loop
```

Any ideas why I still get a unique constraint error?

Comment: Can you post the exact code ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that table c contain more than one row:

```
FOR a IN (select * from table_a) LOOP
  select seq.nextval into id1 from dual;

  insert into table_b (primarykey, value1...)
  select id1, value1... from table_c;    
  -- the same id1 will be used for many rows 
  -- and cause `UNIQUE` constraint violation

end loop;
```

I would rewrite it as:

```
INSERT INTO table_b(primarykey, value1...)
SELECT seq.nextval, value1, ...
FROM table_c
WHERE ....;
```